# C# synchronize 2 lists of different types by time

Tags: c#, list, synchronization

I have 2 lists of different types. I think for now it doesn't matter what types that are.
Both types have an information about occurance which is in ticks (but can also be a DateTime).

What I want to do is, to synchronize these 2 lists by time so for example i can iterate through all elements in the order how they occured in time.

```
Example: // in this example List has elements called A_NUM or B_NUM depending on a type of list and number after '_' will represent order at which this elements/events occured 
ListA = {A_2, A_3, A_5}
ListB = {B_1, B_4, B_6}
```

And the result after synchronization will be something like this:

```
ResultList = {B_1, A_2, A_3, B_4, A_5, B_6}
```

Is it somehow possible to make such mixed list? Or I have to create some auxiliary List or Dictionary which will tell me synchronized order of this 2 lists?

**EDIT:**

One list is a list of eye fixations. Fixation have a position, duration, ... and also occurance attributes.
Second list is a list of some changes of text, for example on line 12 column 3 there was a char 'x' added at some time `t`.

And I want to iterate through these 2 lists simultaneously. I mean at time `t1` fixation occured at position `x,y`. At time `t2` there was a text change at position `u,v`, so I want to iterate through these events in the order as they occured in time.

Note: YES both lists are sorted by time. It is a sequence of fixations and sequence of text changes.

Comment: The types of the lists Matter, what is the Type of the `ResultList`?

Comment: use `concat()` for this

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. Just thinking about it and so I thought best way to get some functional solution is to ask experienced guys here.
@JamesRalston It is just an example. I want to know if it is possible to create such synchronized list (for now I'm opened to create any type)

Comment: Those lists are already sorted?

Comment: @Gondil the reason I ask is because the List will need to have some kind of generic type that can allow both the type of `ListA` and the type of `ListB` to be added. So if they are in fact to different types, they will need to have some common implementation to get the value you want to order by

Comment: Not sure what's the question. The types **does** matter. If they share common base class/interface, you could store the result in `List<CommonTYpeOrInterface>`. Or in `List<object>` if they are totally different. If the question is how to produce that result, it should be pretty standard merge algorithm. So what's the question again?

Comment: @IvanStoev this 2 types doesn't have common base class. So maybe `List<object>` will be the solution. And what is my question? Want to know the most suitable solution for time synchronization of 2 sorted list of different type. I don't know how to formulate it more clearly.

Comment: Ok, then use `List<object>` and populate it with a standard merge algorithm (like the one used in MergeSort).

Comment: How large are those lists? If they are large you might not want to copy them to another list just for enumeration.

Comment: It depends on what is large :) I'm not bounded, they can have millions of elements but probably only few thousands maybe hundreds.

Comment: @Evk if he/she needs to play back the events in order, a new list would likely be on of the more efficient ways to do so. you could use a list of object and sort them with merge sort, but the answer I have below will also work (and uses the MSFT implementation of sort) You will still need to box the objects when trying to use them while enumerating. unless you can define a common set of utulities to add to the interface.

Comment: @JamesRalston check Peter's answer - this is the correct approach, because you don't need to allocate new list, copy all (potentially millions) items there, sort that list. You can just enumerate them both together (because they are already sorted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question strongly suggests a merge sort as the basic implementation detail. You have two inputs, both sorted, and just want them merged together in sequence.

The main difficulty implied by your question is that you are trying to merge sequences of two completely unrelated types. Ordinarily, you'd merge sequences of the same type, and so could easily manipulate them together. Barring that, they'd at least share a base class or interface type, so that you could treat them as a single generalized type. But it seems, from your question, that this is not the case.

Given that, I think the most straight-forward approach is still to use a merge sort, but to provide a mechanism for the sort to access the relevant property (ticks, `DateTime`, whatever). The sort would return the merged sequences, in correct order, as the `object` type (i.e. the only base type common to both inputs) and the caller would then have to cast back to the individual types for whatever purpose.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
private static IEnumerable<TBase> Merge<TBase, T1, T2, TValue>(
        IEnumerable<T1> sequence1, IEnumerable<T2> sequence2,
        Func<T1, TValue> valueSelector1, Func<T2, TValue> valueSelector2)
    where T1 : TBase
    where T2 : TBase
    where TValue : IComparable<TValue>
{
    IEnumerator<T1> enumerator1 = sequence1.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator<T2> enumerator2 = sequence2.GetEnumerator();
    bool notDone1 = enumerator1.MoveNext(),
        notDone2 = enumerator2.MoveNext();

    while (notDone1 && notDone2)
    {
        TValue value1 = valueSelector1(enumerator1.Current),
            value2 = valueSelector2(enumerator2.Current);

        if (value1.CompareTo(value2) <= 0)
        {
            yield return enumerator1.Current;
            notDone1 = enumerator1.MoveNext();
        }
        else
        {
            yield return enumerator2.Current;
            notDone2 = enumerator2.MoveNext();
        }
    }

    while (notDone1)
    {
        yield return enumerator1.Current;
        notDone1 = enumerator1.MoveNext();
    }

    while (notDone2)
    {
        yield return enumerator2.Current;
        notDone2 = enumerator2.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
class A
{
    public int Value { get; }

    public A(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

class B
{
    public int Value { get; }

    public B(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int minCount = 5, maxCount = 15, maxValue = 50;
    Random random = new Random();
    int listACount = random.Next(minCount, maxCount),
        listBCount = random.Next(minCount, maxCount);
    A[] listA = RandomOrderedSequence(random, maxValue, listACount).Select(i => new A(i)).ToArray();
    B[] listB = RandomOrderedSequence(random, maxValue, listBCount).Select(i => new B(i)).ToArray();

    Console.WriteLine("listA: ");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", listA.Select(a => a.Value)));
    Console.WriteLine("listB: ");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", listB.Select(b => b.Value)));

    foreach (object o in Merge<object, A, B, int>(listA, listB, a => a.Value, b => b.Value))
    {
        A a = o as A;

        if (a != null)
        {
            // Do something with object of type A
            Console.WriteLine($"a.Value: {a.Value}");
        }
        else
        {
            // Must be a B. Do something with object of type B
            B b = (B)o;

            Console.WriteLine($"b.Value: {b.Value}");
        }
    }
}

static IEnumerable<int> RandomOrderedSequence(Random random, int max, int count)
{
    return RandomSequence(random, max, count).OrderBy(i => i);
}

static IEnumerable<int> RandomSequence(Random random, int max, int count)
{
    while (count-- > 0)
    {
        yield return random.Next(max);
    }
}
```

In your case, you would of course replace types `A` and `B` with the types you're actually using, provide appropriate selectors, and then do whatever you like with each instance returned as the merged, in-order sequence.

Note that even if the types do turn out to share some common basis for which they can be compared and merged, I would still recommend a merge sort over simply concatenating and merging the result. The merge sort is a *much* more efficient way to merge already-ordered data into a single sequence of ordered data.

Answer (score 0):

You need the lists to implement a common interface so they can be compared. For example:

```
public interface ISynchronizable 
{
    long GetTicks();
}
```

So you need to have the two object implement this, like so:

```
public class Fixation : ISynchronizable
{
    public long GetTicks()
    {
        // get the ticks
    }
    // some other code
}

public class TextChange: ISynchronizable
{
    public long GetTicks()
    {
        // get the ticks
    }

    // some other code
}
```

Then the result list would be created like this:

```
public List<ISynchronizable> list = new List<ISynchronizable>();
list.AddRange(fixationList);
list.AddRange(textChangeList);
resultList = list.OrderBy(e => e.GetTicks()).ToList();
```